# Google Apps Script To Combine Arrays as Columns Instead of Rows

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

**Background**

In Google Apps Script I would like to make a new array that combines two arrays vertically as columns, not as additional rows. I understand it's pretty easy to add additional rows using .concat or .push but this extends the array vertically.

Here's the code:

```
var ar1 = [[1,3,5],
           [2,4,6]];

var ar2 = [[7,9,11],
           [8,10,12]];
```

**Desired Outcome**

When running ar3 I would like the desired output to be:

```
[[1,3,5,7,9,11]
 [2,4,6,8,10,12]]
```

**Things I've Tried**

I think this could be run as a function through concat. I have tried something like the below to no avail:

```
var ar3 = ar2.forEach(function (row){ ar1.concat([row[0],row[1],row[2]]); });
```

Could this be made even simpler with .map and return? (I know the below is very wrong, but just an example.)

```
var ar3 = ar1.map(function (row){ return ar1[row].concat(ar2[row]); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)'s index like this:

```js
var ar1 = [[1,3,5],
       [2,4,6]];

var ar2 = [[7,9,11],
       [8,10,12]];

const out = ar1.map((row,i) => row.concat(ar2[i]))

console.info(out)
```

Comment: Hi I think this is tailored to JavaScript but do you know how this would be optimized for Google Apps script?

Comment: @Zack Apps script is JavaScript(with a few  inbuilt libraries)

Comment: Okay yes, it worked! Sorry I'm quite new to this. 

Just curious, for my own education, how might you do it using function?

Comment: @Zack It is a function. just written differently. `function(row,i){return row.concat(ar2[i]))}`. You could  search the above link (mdn) for "arrow functions"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, without using concat:

```js
var ar1 = [
  [1, 3, 5],
  [2, 4, 6]
];

var ar2 = [
  [7, 9, 11],
  [8, 10, 12]
];



const result = ar1.map((x, i) => [...x, ...ar2[i]]);
console.log('result', result)
```